# How to get the string information, the same as its output in the console, of an attribute?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it possible to use a method to get the same result like the output in line 35？I have tried different methods, but none of them can achieve this.

```py
In [34]: class Foo:
    ...:     def test(self):
    ...:         pass
    ...: 

In [35]: Foo.test
Out[35]: <function __main__.Foo.test(self)>  # how to use a method to get the output in code?

In [36]: Foo.test.__str__
Out[36]: <method-wrapper '__str__' of function object at 0x107cd2b80>

In [37]: str(Foo.test)
Out[37]: '<function Foo.test at 0x107cd2b80>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are using a too clever Python interpretor. This line:

```
Out[35]: <function __main__.Foo.test(self)>
```

is very informative because it contains the qualified name of the class. Unfortunately, neither the *standard* `str` nor `repr` applied to a function provide it. Just use the simpler `idle` or `python` to make sure. You would get:

```
>>> Foo.test
<function Foo.test at 0x107cd2b80>
```

exactly what `str` returns.

You can certainly build it *by hand* optionaly with the help of the `inspect` module but it will require some work... You must read the doc of your tool (is it `ipython`?) to have the exact description of what it displays, or specify (precisely) what you want.

Comment: Got it, many thanks for your help, i use ipython.